# Why cant I square the series when doing maclaurin expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

So the task says: Do the Maclaurin expansion of the given term: $$f(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

what I did was: https://ibb.co/19Ddd8d

The way i tried to solve the task was wrong, I know that i should derive and than multiply with x and that would give me the correct Maclaurin expansion.

But why couldn't I square both sides and then multiply with x instead of deriving  and than multiplying with x?

Comment: The second image is incomprehensible.

Comment: $(\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^m)^2=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{m+n} \ne \sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{2m}$!!!!!

Comment: Especially those $/^2$ and $/\cdot x$ (I guess?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should sniff around some texts about generating functions to get more comfortable with these calculations. You can certainly square both sides and multiply by $x$. For example:

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m$$

Squaring both sides yields
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} &= \left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m\right)^2\\
&= (1+x+x^2+\cdots )(1+x+x^2+\cdots)\\
&= (1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots)\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (m+1)x^m.
\end{align}

Notice that you'd need to calculate the square of the polynomial. Fortunately it is easy enough in this case.

Finally multiplying by $x$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (m+1)x^{m+1}\\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} mx^{m}
\end{align}

On the other hand, we can take a derivative and be done with it. Taking the derivative of the right hand side is fairly straightforward, as we just take the derivative of every term individually.

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{d}{dx} &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m\frac{d}{dx}\\
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} mx^{m-1}\\
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} mx^{m}\\
\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} &= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} mx^{m}\\
\end{align}

I forget if one should really take caution while taking the derivative of a sum $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m$ as the first term without adjusting indices becomes $0(\frac{1}{x})$, but perhaps someone with more experience can speak to this.

Comment: The first term $x^0$ is just the constant $1$, so its derivative is zero.